# imgur upload using classic asp or javascript (and IE compliant)?

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, asp-classic

I'm trying to create an image upload form on my site that uploads directly to imgur for hosting, but I have to use classic ASP or javascript, and the only javascript example does not work in IE. Does anyone know if these is easily accomplished?

Here's the api: http://api.imgur.com/examples

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a jQuery plugin to accomplish a javascript upload

http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/upload